# New variables for the Drake equation?

Tags: space, aliens, civilization

Has any scientist or sci-fi writer proposed adding new variables to the Drake equation? Science in every area has progressed a great deal since the days of Enrico Fermi and his contemporaries, after all. Has there been a serious attempt to make an "updated" Drake equation? Maybe one that includes some basic social factors?

Comment: Have you looked at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drake_equation#Modifications), by any chance? There's a decent subsection there on the topic.

Comment: Randall Munroe has proposed a new version of the equation with a new variable: https://xkcd.com/384/

Comment: @HDE226868 Great link! I wasn't familiar with any of these proposals.

Comment: @Renan I'm a simple man. I see an XKCD link, I upvote.

Comment: This reads more like a question about the possibility for extraterrestrial life in our galaxy, rather than a question about building fictional "worlds" where you can have as much or as little extraterrestrial life as you want.

Comment: The Drake equation itself has never been intended to be taken seriously... It is just a discussion opener, a purely heuristic starting point. So that I doubt that anybody has bothered to make a serious attempt to update an equation which was not serious to begin with.

Comment: @Renan That sounds like an answer to me!

Comment: @AlexP, sorry, bud- You're just wrong. It's very serious, and very much a study in updates.  See : https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/48096/how-many-planets-with-sapient-life-can-i-expect-to-find-in-a-random-galaxy/48098#48098

Comment: A slightly different approach to the question might have been: "Have any of the existing variables been quantified with a greater degree of certainty?". If you go and ask this on [astronomy.se], you might get a better reception. Also related on [space.se] is [Are we alone after all? Understanding the recent re-evaluation of the Drake Equation](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/28103/are-we-alone-after-all-understanding-the-recent-re-evaluation-of-the-drake-equa)- worth takeing a look at. @Joe might be interested too.

Comment: The big problem with the Drake equation is that at least one of it's terms is currently indeterminate, so the answer is indeterminate.

Comment: @Jem, check out the Rare Earth Theory. It’s pretty much what you’re looking for. It tries to also explain the Fermi Paradox by explaining that intelligent life is so rare that it is likely that there are only 1-2 civilizations per galaxy.